# Auto loading setting file depending on environment with Azure Functions 2.x and VS

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

I need to support multiple settings file for different environment, e.g. Dev, Prod, for Azure Functions.

Below is what I tried, I want to find out **if it is possible to make the settings file loaded automicatlly without step 2, and 3**, like ASP.NET CORE 2.x.

Step 1: The settings files below are defined,

MyAppSettings.development.json

```
{
  ThirdParty: {  
   "Key": "Key1" 
  }
}
```

MyAppSettings.production.json

```
{
  ThirdParty: {  
   "Key": "Key2" 
  }
}
```

Step 2: Define an environment variable that is used to load the settings file

```
Settings_File_To_Load: MyAppSettings.development.json
```

Is it possible to reuse a variable instead of creating a new one, e.g. `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`

Step 3: Read the value of "`Settings_File_To_Load`", and load the content of the file.

Is it possible to let the file automicatlly loaded?

Again, is it possible to make the settings file loaded automicatlly without step 2, and 3?

Visual studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic override for the settings file- the runtime is expecting local.settings.json and you must override this if you want to use multiple settings files in local development.

If you are changing the settings as part of publishing the solution to Azure, you can override the settings in the local.settings.json as part of the publish profile. You can use the [slots feature in Azure Functions](https://cmatskas.com/introduction-azure-functions-deployment-slots/) to allow for multiple configs/environments within the service.

[image: image of VS 2017 showing the publish to Azure screen]

[image: Image of the App Settings window in VS2017]

Comment: I knew the override feature from local.setting.json, but it cannot be used for more than one environment on Azure. Can the slot feature fit the scenario?

Comment: Slots are completely seperate instances of your app, so they can be configured individually and have different publish profiles. You can also swap the code between slots while keeping the settings the same. For example, if you have a dev slot and a production slot, you can swap your dev code into prod while keeping the production settings intact.

Comment: sounds great, I need to have a look. Thx.